# Why does the limit not exist?

Tags: limits

I'm working on partial derivatives and I'm taking calculus IV. I need some help understanding why part $ c$'s limit "does not exist".

Find each of the following limits, or explain that the limit does not exist.

Let $f(x,y) =\begin{cases} 1&, y \geq x^4\\ 
             1&, y \leq 0 \\
             0&, \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$

a) limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,1)$;

b) limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches, $(2,3)$;

c) limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$.

Is part $c$ "does not exist" because the limits of part a and b are different? Or am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: no, parts a) and b) don't have anything to do with c). to prove the limit doesn't exists try to find two sequences $(x_n, y_n)$ and $(x'_n, y'_n)$ converging to $(0,0)$ along which the limits of $f$ will be different. (hint - in your case you should aim for limits $1$ and $0$ naturally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you approach $(0,0)$ along the path $x = 0$, then we get a limit of $1$, since we always fall under either the first or the second cases of the piecewise function.

If you approach $(0,0)$ along the path $y = 0.5x^4$, then we get a limit of $0$, since we always fall under the third case of the piecewise function.

Since different paths yielded different limits, it follows that:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)
$$
does not exist.

Comment: Did you just choose to use the equation y=0.5x^4? Is it possible to pick something else like y=x?

Comment: Draw a picture. You want to find a function $y = g(x)$ such that:
$$
0 \leq g(x) \leq x^4
$$
for all $(x,y)$ in some neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. Choosing $g(x) = x$ doesn't quite work.

Comment: Oh! I see! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a limit to exist, it must be independent of the path of approach. Note that this is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for existence.

Approaching the origin along $y=x^4$ and along the path $y = ky^4 $ where $0<k<1$ yield different limits (try it), and so this particular limit cannot exist.

Comment: @ Karen - Because the limit is path-dependent. Limits must be path independent to exist.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification!